# In MVC, who is in charge of handling observers?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, observer-pattern

(I'm writing a large MATLAB GUI that makes significant use of MVC, so my example is written in MATLAB. However, I believe this question is language-agnostic. Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

I have a class `Model` which is obviously the model for my MVC application. Suppose I have the following:

```
classdef Model < handle
    properties
        objectA
        objectB
        objectC
    end
end
```

`objectA`, `objectB`, and `objectC` are all objects that can be observed:

```
classdef objectA < handle
    events
        ObjectAEvent
    end
    methods
        function raise(this)
            this.notify('ObjectAEvent', someEventData);
        end
     end
end
```

etc.

Now say I want my `View` to respond to changes to my `Model`. In particular I want the `View` to respond to the `ObjectAEvent` event. There are two ways to do this:

1. Let the `View` directly subscribe to the `ObjectAEvent` event. We've now coupled the `View` into the internals of the `Model`, which I believe violates the Law of Demeter. I'm pretty sure this also violates the concept of MVC by definition.
2. Let the `Model` "forward" the event to the `View`, as follows.

   ```
   classdef Model < handle
       properties
           objectA
           objectB
           objectC

           listeners
       end
       events
           eventFromObjectA
           ...
       end
       methods
           function this = Model
               this.listeners(1) = addlistener(this.objectA, 'ObjectAEvent', @(src, eventdata) this.notify('eventFromObjectA', eventdata);
               ...
           end
       end
   end
   ```

   Now the `View` directly observes the `Model`, but the `Model` has to pass the events and associated data to the `View`. I suppose this is kind of the point of MVC, but now there's a coupling between each `object_` and the `Model` directly. I suppose the `Model` ought to know about his `object_`s, but this still feels... clunky.

Which approach is more correct? Are there other alternatives which are cleaner than either of these?

(Answers may have examples in any OOP language; I'm just most familiar with MATLAB.)

Comment: After writing out my question my gut says (2) since the `Model` is supposed to send out updates to the `View` and the `View` changes accordingly. Still though, it seems like I'm adding more to the `Model` than should be necessary...

Comment: Model-View-Controller and Observer are two different software patterns that have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: In the MVC pattern, it is very unusual to have a single class that can be identified as "the Model". The Model of the MVC pattern consists of all the classes that are not involved in the UI. It is normal for View or Controller classes to access only parts of the Model.

Comment: `We've now coupled the View into the internals of the Model, which I believe violates the Law of Demeter. I'm pretty sure this also violates the concept of MVC by definition.` The second point is wrong. Views *do* know the model. By definition, view code changes more often, so you don't want model code being coupled to it directly. As for Law of Demeter, you'd have to show *why* you think it violates it. It's not a hard and fast principle, either, despite it's name having the word "Law" in it. It's nearly impossible not to violate it at some point.

Comment: I disagree with @RobertHarvey in that MVC Views are often Observers of Model classes. The patterns are indeed related; one isn't required to use Observer with MVC, however.

Comment: MVC isn't about total decoupling. It's about avoiding coupling to elements that are unstable. Views tend to be less stable than the model, because they're the UI (users tend to want new ways to view, etc.) E.g. how many times the GUI for Microsoft Word has changed, yet the model of a document has not changed much. Views are directly coupled to the model classes because they're more stable. Model classes are coupled to views via the Observer pattern. The Observer API is very stable, even if the views that implement it are not. So it's OK to have coupling the way you have described it.

Comment: If you use a real object rather than `objectA`, say `engineTemperature`, then your view that displays the temperature would surely *know* what it's displaying. It's normal for views to be coupled to the model elements they display. The other way around, however, is different. `engineTemperature` should not know how it's being displayed, or who's displaying it, etc. It (as a Subject in the Observer pattern) only knows it has Observers, which all support the Observer API. Have a look at http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController

Comment: @Fuhrmanator write up your last two comments as an answer and I'd accept it. I think it's good insight! I think you've established that the `View` ought to be coupled (since it needs to know what info it's displaying) and therefore approach #1 in my question would be fine. The next question, then, would be - how can we minimize the impact of changes to the classes it's coupled to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Let the `View` directly subscribe to the `ObjectAEvent` event. We've now coupled the View into the internals of the Model, which I believe violates the Law of Demeter. I'm pretty sure this also violates the concept of MVC by definition.

MVC isn't about *total* decoupling. It's about avoiding coupling to elements that are unstable. As for Law of Demeter, you'd have to show why you think it violates it. It's not a hard and fast principle, either, despite its name having the word "Law" in it. It's nearly impossible not to violate it at some point.

View classes tend to be less *stable* than the model classes, because views are part of the user interface. Users tend to want new ways to view information (it's hard to get the views right the first time), etc. E.g. how many times has the GUI for Microsoft Word changed, yet the model of a document (think of paragraphs, words, characters, fonts, styles, etc.) has not changed much?

In MVC, views can be directly coupled to the model classes, because model classes tend to be more stable. MVC makes this assumption as a design choice. If model classes change (it can happen), then all bets are off for those changes being isolated to the model. You'll probably have to change the views, too.

Model classes have to communicate with the Views, but MVC wants to avoid direct coupling. We get around this problem by disguising Views as "Observers." The Observer API is very stable, even if the views that implement it are not. So as far as I understand MVC, it's OK to have coupling the way you have described it in point #1.

Let's use a real object rather than ObjectA, say `engineTemperature`. The view that displays the temperature would surely know what it's displaying. It might add the units "degrees C" since the view knows the value is a temperature. It might use the color red if the temperature exceeds some upper value. It's normal for views to be directly coupled to the model elements they display.

The other way around, however, is different. `engineTemperature` should not know how it's being displayed, what colors are being used, who's displaying it, etc., since that knowledge would make it tightly coupled to the views, and it would lose its stability. Any change in the view might "break" the temperature object. So, with MVC and Observer, `engineTemperature` (as a Subject in the Observer pattern) only knows it has Observers, which all support the Observer API.

Have a look at http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController for more info on MVC and other UI designs.